# Why is jQuery failing to load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this very simple page at the root of my application. The following fails to load jQuery. However if I remove **~/** from the path, jQuery loads and the alert works. What's the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First verify your "~" path is correct.  This looks like you are confusing a server side directive with client side.

```
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js") %>'></script>
```

And then I would recommend moving your document.ready script block to "just above" the closing body tag.

Comment: Not like there is an ASP.NET tag :))

Comment: Sorry, missed the asp.net tag.

Answer (score 1):

The following link will explain you well about path format in aspx page:

[**ASP.NET Web Site Paths**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

The code line change to as follow will help you as it take reference from the root of your site.

```
<script src='/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js'></script>
```

See this from above link:

> You can use the ~ operator in any path-related property in server
>   controls. The ~ operator is recognized only for server controls and in
>   server code. You cannot use the ~ operator for client elements.

Comment: <script src='/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js'></script>  did the trick

Answer (score 0):

try the simple thing

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> 
</head>
```

when you make head runtat='server' then you  ~/  should work ok dear

:D

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning that in MVC 4 Razor 2, and ASP.Net Web Pages **2**, the "tilde slash feature" should work just fine.

e.g.
`<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />`

You will find the above in the default scaffolding (`_Layout.cshtml or vbhtml`) when

- adding either a `New Web Site -> ASP.Net Web Site (Razor 2)` or
- adding a new `Project -> C#/VB -> Web -> ASP.Net MVC 4 Web Application -> Razor Engine`

---

REFs:

> [The Top Features in ASP.NET Web Pages 2](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/whats-new/top-features-in-web-pages-2)
>
> You can now include the ~ operator in markup to reference the site root without using the Href function. (That is, the Razor parser can now find and resolve the ~ operator without requiring an explicit method call to Href.) The Href method still works, so this is not a breaking change.
>
> For example, if you previously had markup like this:
>
> `<a href="@Href("~/Default.cshtml")">Home</a>`
>
> You can now use markup like this:
>
> `<a href="~/Default.cshtml">Home</a>`